# Insert multiple rows with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a multicheckbox in a `<form>` tag like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="<?php echo $menuItems['id']; ?>">
```

I ask this form with this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['subgruppe'])) {
        $ids = array();

    foreach ($_POST['del'] as $pval) {
        $ids[] = (int) $pval;
    }

    $ids = implode(',', $ids);
    echo "groupids";
    echo $ids;
    echo "userid:";
    echo $_POST['userid'];
```

This shows me a result like this:

```
groupids13,9...userid:5
```

I need a statment that give me a result like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_groups (usergroup, userid) VALUE (13,5),(9,5)
```

...
Can you give me a hint how i can check this?
I think I can handel a solution that give me:
(13,5),(9,5)... into a variable.

THanks a lot:)

Comment: Can You post a $_POST ?

Comment: What do you mean with "post a $_POST "

Comment: Show us what $_POST contains after posting a form.

Comment: the  post-content are all groupids in a array and the userid from this code: <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $menuItem['id']; ?>">

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to build a single string for all of your `INSERTS` simply insert while you are looping.

For example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_groups (usergroup, userid) VALUE (:usergroup, :userid)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach ($_POST['del'] as $pval) {
    $stmt->execute(array(':usergroup'=>(int) $pval, 
                         ':userid'=>$_POST['userid']
    ));
}
```

Comment: To the OP: The benefit here is prepared statements are fast to re-execute with new parameters.

Comment: How can I extend foreach syntax, If I want to add one more array :usertag'=>$_POST['usertag']

Comment: @BobiReshovski then `$_POST['del']` need to be a multi-dimension array